# Security of a laptop order

Tags: antimalware, rootkits

What's the likelihood of a laptop being compromised when it comes directly from a trusted computer store or a large, known computer technology company? Would there be any liability if malware or rookit was discovered?

What checks / scans would you perform if you wanted to be as sure as possible that it hasn't been compromised?

Comment: *"Would there be any liability if malware or rookit was discovered?"* - this part is off-topic since purely legal. Try [law.se] for this.

Answer (score 1):

For the average user in a western country who buys from an established vendor the risk is likely low. Vendors typically set up all systems the same way with a common image and thus any compromise would affect a larger user base and thus gets probably quickly noticed.

But if the government is interested in messing with you then the risk is much higher.  It is known that government agencies might divert shipments in order to manipulate the content. If there is such a targeted attack against you it is likely that you will not be able to figure it out by running some common scans or doing common checks since they would make sure that the attack is not that obvious.